# AUtomapper - custom property mapping

Tags: automapper

Usually the property names are the same,but many properties have on one side a prefix.

Classes may look like this

```
public class User
{
     public string Name{ get; set; }
     public string Adress{ get; set; }
     public string SureName{ get; set; }
} 

public class UserEntity
{
     public string Name{ get; set; }
     public string XxxAdress{ get; set; }
     public string YyyYyySureName{ get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to create a rule,which would compare the property names using the `EndsWith()` function ?

I don't want use the `.ForMember` on every object, there are to many objects to maintain this.

Comment: very possible but not with automapper =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RecognizePrefixes` or `RecognizeDestinationPrefixes` for common prefixes/postfixes, and AutoMapper will match things up for you appropriately. These methods can be found on the Profile classes.

Comment: Can you open a GH issue describing how it isn't working?